# Remove first characters of values in comma separated string

Tags: c#, string

I have the below comma separated  string in application

```
string s= "01334644,1376673,1378437,01499972,1507527,01522373,01551596";
```

I want to remove  the first character of each values in the string ..if it is zero

Finally i need a string like this

```
string s = "1334644,1376673,1378437,1499972,1507527,1522373,1551596"; // out put string  1
```

Comment: string.Split() to get comma separated values, then string.SubString or even string.Parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.Split` to get all tokens and `TrimStart('0')` to remove leading zeros, `String.Join` to concatenate the final string again with commas:

```
string s= "01334644,1376673,1378437,01499972,1507527,01522373,01551596";
s = string.Join(",", s.Split(',').Select(str => str.TrimStart('0')));
```

> ... remove the first character ...

If you don't want to remove all leading zeros but only one at the maximum:

```
s = string.Join(",", s.Split(',')
    .Select(str => str.StartsWith("0") ? str.Substring(1) : str));
```

Comment: Tim Thanks for the solution  ... 

string s1= 1334644,1376673,1378437,1499972,1507527,1522373";
string s2 = 1334644,1378437,1499972,1507527,1507527,1334644,1334644,1334644,1334644";

from  above strings can we generate a new string which contains a  missed values of s1 string by comparing s1 and s2 

it should be  :

string s3 = "1376673,1522373";

Thanks

Comment: @user3848181 remove `Join` call, so get a collections of string. Then use `Except` LINQ method, and then join. I'm not sure, maybe in your case also `Distinct` is required. Anyway, it's difficult to answer in comment clearly, and question was different.

Answer (score 2):

You can work directly in the source string to remove all 0 preceded by a comma:

```
string s2 = s.Replace(",0", ",").TrimStart('0')
```

Comment: What about the first 0, i mean the 0 in 01334644?

Comment: you can add `.TrimStart('0')` before Replace.

Comment: I was editing to add the TrimStart call - thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it :

```
string s = "01334644,1376673,1378437,01499972,1507527,01522373,01551596";
String result = String.Join(",", s.Split(',')
                .Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString()));
```

Comment: Presumes that all values are `int`s, `01334644x` would be problematic ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 string s= "01334644,1376673,1378437,01499972,1507527,01522373,01551596"; 
 var str = string.Join(",", s.Split(',').Select(strCheck => strCheck.StartsWith("0") ? strCheck.Substring(1) : strCheck));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the value to int und back to String:

```
var values = s.Split(',').Cast<int>();
s = string.Join(",", values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] str = null;
string s = "01334644,1376673,1378437,01499972,1507527,01522373,01551596";
str = s.Split(",");
s = "";
for (int i = 0; i <= str.Length - 1; i++) {
    s = s + Conversion.str(i).Substring(1) + " ,";
}
    // to avoid the last comma
Interaction.MsgBox(s.Trim(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about regular expressions?

```
string s = "01334644,1376673,1378437,01499972,1507527,01522373,01551596";
string result = Regex.Replace(s, @"0*(\d+)", "$1");
```

`0*` means any quantity of zeros, `\d+` means one or more digits, `( )` say to make a group, that we can call with `$1`.

Tested, I think, even works fine with strings like `"00,000001972000,000"`. In this case several zeros became single.